# Extract specific column from files of a directory into a new file

Tags: python, shell, awk

I have a collection of 11064 files, and they all have same file extension ReadsPerGene.out.tab. They are in a directory. All the files have 556 lines,  4 columns.

```
Filenames look like this:
SRR123.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
SRR456.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
SRR555.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
DRR789.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
...

File looks like this:
for SRR123ReadsPerGene.out.tab        for SRR789.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
A    45   67   78                       A    89O  90   34
B    17   40   23                       B    129  96   45
C    27   50   19                       C     60  56   91
...  ...  ...  ...                     ...   ...  ...  ...
```

First, I want to judge whether the first column of all the files are the same.

If it's true, I want to create an output.txt file with 665 lines, 11065 columns. The 1th column is the first column of every file(because they are same). And 2th of 11065th columns of output.txt are the 2th column of each input file, I want to add the specific filename as the first line for every column.

```
The output.txt looks like this:

      SRR123                SRR789              SRR456        ...
A        45                 89O                66            ...
B        17                 129                480           ...
C        27                  60                78            ...
...      ...               ...               ...             ...
```

**The following are my answers. **

**1. get all filenames**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
filepath=/home/shared/maize/bam_rsem
cd ${filepath}
for file in $(ls *.ReadsPerGene.out.tab)
do
   echo $file >> ~/filename.txt
done
```

2. **get all the first column in one file**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
OUT=result2.txt
touch $OUT
filepath=/home/shared/maize/bam_rsem/
for file in $(cat filename.txt)
do
   filePATH=`echo ${filepath}$file`
   cut -f 1 $filePATH | sed 1i\ ${file} >$OUT.tmp1
   paste $OUT $OUT.tmp1 >$OUT.tmp
   rm $OUT.tmp1
   mv $OUT.tmp $OUT
done
```

3. **compare whether the first column is identical with other columns in result2.txt**
*I have no idea now.*
4. **create an output.txt**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
OUT=result2.txt
touch $OUT
filepath=/home/shared/maize/bam_rsem/
for file in $(cat filename.txt)
do
   filePATH=`echo ${filepath}$file`
   cut -f 1 $filePATH | sed 1i\ ${file} >$OUT.tmp1
   paste $OUT $OUT.tmp1 >$OUT.tmp
   rm $OUT.tmp1
   mv $OUT.tmp $OUT
done

cut -f 1 result2.txt >$OUT.tmp2
paste $OUT.tmp2 $OUT >$OUT.tmp3
rm $OUT.tmp2
mv $OUT.tmp3 $OUT
```

What should I do for my script? It is really slow to execute my script in Linux.
Or should I  write up a Python script to handle it,but I have never learned python or Perl and I just know a little about Linux.

I'm so sorry that my English is poor, I can not reply in time. Anyway, thanks for all your answers!

Comment: A slightly better version of your previous Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099775/extract-specific-column-from-similar-files-of-a-directory-into-a-new-file . Someone has probably downvoted (not me, yet) because you haven't included your best attempt to solve your problem. Please update your Q to include your best attempt to code a solution to your problem (it's interesting). Look at `xargs` and `gnu-parallel`, they can possible help with having so many files to process. ....

Comment: I  would also pre-scan your files and save the filenames of all correct files into a text file, then use that file to "drive" your process. Good luck.

Comment: AND you might want to explain what is the final use for your data, as it is hard to imagine a spreadsheet that has 11064 columns being usable (or loadable). This data is likely better stored in a database, with a properly designed set of tables and keys. Again, good luck!

Comment: @ shellter, thanks, I have get a filname list in filename.txt.

Comment: `awk` supports Multidimensional Arrays using a sequence of characters as the index. GNU `awk` goes further and supports `arr[i][j]` indexing. See[`awk` Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) Your storage requirements are not unreasonable, your data set for one-column (assuming 4-bytes per values) is roughly `24M`. You will need a single array for the first column of the first file you can compare against the remaining to ensure they are equal. You could just build an array of the 2nd column for each file and output in the `END` rule.

Comment: @shellter，I'm solving a biology problem.  I really need a result like that.

Comment: Your options are really `awk`, python or a compiled language. A shell script would be horribly slow. In python or a compiled language like C/C++, you could handle the storage just by reading/parsing all values into an allocated array/vector of structures containing the filename and an integer array representing the 2nd-column values. You would check against the 1st column on the initial read and storage of the 2nd column data. Then it is just a matter of writing the information back out in the format you require.

Comment: @ David Rankin - ReinstateMonica, Thanks. I'm so sorry that I'm new to programming. So I don't know where to start and what is best for solving my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One in awk. The filenames to process are in `files` (due to large number of them):

```
$ cat files
SRR123.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
SRR789.ReadsPerGene.out.tab
```

The awk program is to run in the directory with the data files (`split`ing the first `.` separated part of the filename for the header, ie. leading path would make the header name pretty lengthy):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
{
    files[NR]=$0                                # hash filenames from file files
}
END{
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {                        # loop files
        nr=0
        split(files[i],t,".")
        h[nr]=h[nr] OFS t[1]                    # build header
        while((getline < files[i])>0) {         # using getline to read data records
            nr++                                # d[++nr] order not same in all awks
            d[nr]=d[nr] OFS $2                  # append data fields to previous
            if(i==1) {                          # get headers from first file
                h[(refnr=nr)]=$1
            } else if($1!=h[nr]) {              # check that they stay the same
                print "Nonmatching field name"
                exit                            # or exit without output
            }
        }
        if(nr!=refnr) {                         # also record count must be the same
            print "Nonmatching record count"
            exit
        }
        close(files[i])
    }
    for(i=0;i<=refnr;i++)                       # output part
        print h[i] d[i]
}' files
```

Output:

```
        SRR123  SRR789
A       45      89O
B       17      129
C       27      60
...     ...     ...
```

*`[++nr] order not same in all awks`*: Apparently some awks prefer `d[++nr]=d[nr] OFS $2` and some `d[nr]=d[++nr] OFS $2` so separate `nr++`  works for both.

**Update**:

If the files are in a different path and the filenames in the file `files` don't have paths included, replace intelligently:

```
split(files[i],t,".")
...
while((getline < files[i])>0) {
```

with

```
file="home/shared/maize/bam_rsem/" files[i]
split(file,t,".")
...
while((getline < file)>0) {
```

AND

```
close(files[i])
```

with

```
close(file)
```

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by  "files[NR]=$0" ? I'm confused. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: GNU awk documents `NR`: _The number of input records awk has processed since the beginning of the program’s execution_. It is used as a key to hash `files`  which stores the filenames from file `files`. `files[1]="SRR123.ReadsPerGene.out.tab"`etc.

Comment: ，Thanks! It does work for my exercise data. But my filename.txt is in /home.wzzuo, and my data are in /home/shared/maize/bam_rsem. The problem is that I can not move them into the same directory. So I want to modify your code, but it doesn't work. I change "while((getline < files[i])>0)" to "while((getline < "/home/shared/maize/bam_rsem/files[i]")>0)". Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it worked in the comments section of this answer.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = sorted(glob.glob("*.log.out", recursive=False))

#dropped_col_1 = list()
#kept_col_2 = list()
drop_files = dict()
keep_files = dict()
ref_file_name = 'SRR123.log.out'
df_ref_file = pd.read_csv(ref_file_name, sep='\t', header=None)
for i, filename in enumerate(files):
    df_file = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None)
    if df_ref_file['0'] != df_file['0']:
        drop_files.update({filename: df_file['0'].tolist()})
        #dropped_col_1.append(df_file['0'].tolist())
    else:
        keep_files.update({filename: df_file['1'].tolist()})        
        #kept_col_2.append(df_file['1'].tolist())

df = pd.DataFrame(keep_files, index=df_ref_file['0'])
df.index.names = ['ID']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# check the shape of the dataframe
df.shape
```

Comment: ， thanks. There is something wrong with my machine. I just can not use pandas now. So if I can use it, I will tell you the result.